# “too much recursion” in onload event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to include a form from one page on one domain to another page on another domain. Here is my code which I put after my block form.

```
function IncludeSrc(src) {
  var s= document.createElement("script");
  s.src = src;
  s.async = true;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
 }
 var onLoadFunc = window.onload;
 window.onload=function(){
   if (typeof(onLoadFunc)=='function') onLoadFunc();
   IncludeSrc('MYADRESS');
 };
```

There is no error in any browser but the form does not load. In Firefox console I found the error `too much recursion`. The address of the script is valid, I checked it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the point of your script. You are calling `window.onload` recursively...

Comment: @nico: Not really, `onLoadFunc` is referring to the function that was **previously** defined in `window.onload`. Of course if you run that code twice, you'd have recursion. See: http://jsfiddle.net/xzwxp/

Comment: var onLoadFunc = window.onload; is the error

Comment: Do some basic debugging, add `console.log` calls to see what is executed. Also make sure that you don't call that code twice, otherwise you have indeed infinite recursion.

Comment: ok...i am not getting any error in firefox

Comment: before that stuff on event `window.onload` there was some OLD logic, i saved OLD `window.onload` logic in `onLoadFunc var`, because i need to do my OLD onload logic and after that i include my form

Comment: And what is the old logic doing? Could that be the problem?

Comment: i think not, because i load that form on native site, and it is all right

Comment: Yeah well, then I don't think there is anything else we can do for you.

Comment: By any chance does the script referred to by MYADDRESS point back to the current script?  That would explain the recursion, I believe.  EDIT: Oh wait, different domain, you said?

Comment: Yeap, i saved site onload logic, and then add my, and call first site logic then my.

Comment: @AntonSementsov - Sorry, didn't follow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're calling `onLoadFunc` within itself.  Regardless of why you'd want to do this, there's no base case for the recursion, so it never bottoms out...

Comment: He is calling whatever `window.onload` referred to **before** he replaced that value. If it is indeed the same function, he would have infinite recursion, but if the code is only called once, it's fine. To prove my point: http://jsfiddle.net/xzwxp/.

Comment: Either way, there's still no well-defined base case for the recursion.

Comment: @Felix Kling: can you be sure that `window.onload` will be called before `var onLoadFunc = window.onload;`?

Comment: @nico: No, you can't,  in fact it is rather unlikely that it will (depends on when the above snippet is executed). Why do you ask?

Comment: There is a base case for the recursion:  `if (typeof(onLoadFunc)=='function')`.

Comment: I don't see where 'recursion' mentioned in this answer came from, but as first comment shows, there is NO recursion. Calling another function from within a function does not constitute recursion.

EDIT: Another demo just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/rguSN/

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't mean there is no recursion at all in OP's case. I meant that calling `onLoadFunc` from within `window.onload` is not a recursion. There can still be any number of things we didn't see from OP that are causing recursion. Incidentally, FF seems to have a much smaller recursion limit (what's the proper term for this? stack size?) than other browsers so it is more likely to complain about recursive functions.

Comment: Let's remember that the bug report is `too much recursion`.  Presumably there is recursion **somewhere**.

Comment: @Felix Kling: well, `window.onload` calls `onLoadFunc` which is defined as `window.onload`, so they should call each other recursively. What am I missing?

Comment: @nico: `onLoadFunc` is whatever `window.onload` was **before** it was overwritten. Example: `window.onload = function() { alert('foo'); }; onLoadFunc = window.onload; window.onload = function() { onLoadFunc();};`. Do you have recursion here? No :)

Comment: @Felix Kling: that is why I am asking how you could be sure that `onLoadFunc = window.onload;` is executed **before** `window.onload`. So does the JS interpreter read all of the JS before executing it or does it execute it as it reads it?

Comment: I must be missing something.  The original definition of `window.onLoad` is assigned to `onLoadFunc`.  Then, `window.onLoad` is assigned a new definition.  If the original definition (now assigned to `onLoadFunc` was a function (i.e., was not nil), it is then called again in the new definition.  If something in there triggers a call to `IncludeSrc()`, then it will be called repeatedly.

Comment: Furthermore, while I may not have been pointing to strict recitation, per se, it is also entirely possible that the call to `IncludeSrc()` within the definition of `IncludeSrc()` might occur repeatedly, depending on the passed argument.  This is the textbook definition of recursion...